# How to link Adobe Flex application to website

Tags: actionscript-3, api, apache-flex, mxml, httpservice

I am creating an Adobe Flex application. I want to use a website like bbc goodfood by using textInput in my application to search for recipes on the goodfood website which would then return results in my application. How could this be done? I can't find APIs to get this to work and not sure how I would do it. Would I use an HTTP Service call to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand your question you do want to research only one site? if so I'm not sure, but if say you would wanted to research worldwide and with that specific on most available globally search engine provider for particular items then YES you can do that!!! I myself use Http service calls for that in my Application regards aktell!

Comment: I just had some spare time to view this BBC Good Food web site and YES you can actually do that easily by way of using a text Input - manually or even running it automatically as well using say Xml that is quiet strait forward. regards aktell

Answer (score 0):

If you really want accomplish such task, you will need help of server-side. As you will be able omit crossdomain policy file (BBC GoodFood don't have it) and parse html pages (Again, BBS GoodFoot doesn't provide API, for searching or recipes. Or you can parse html pages in the application, but you will not have cache for parsed results, etc.) and prepare result for your client side written on Flex. But It's only an idea, and I *strongly don't recommend* to do it.